# Why javascript function has instance per call?

Tags: javascript, function, object, instance

The javascript introduction says:
When I have code like below:

```
var Person=function(name){ 
     this.name=name; 
     this.sayHello=function(){return 'Hello '+name;} 
}
```

Whenever I instantiate a "Person", there will be a copy of "sayHello" function in the memory. To reduce this memory consumption, I can change the code like below:

```
var Person=(function(){ 
     var sayHello=function(){return 'Hello '+name} 
     return function(name){ 
         this.name=name 
         this.sayHello=sayHello 
     } 
})()
```

In this way, there'll not be multiple copies of sayHello()

My questions are:

1. For the 1st type of code, what's the benefit except wasting more memory?
2. Should we write code in the 2nd way, or javascript should avoid one copy for one function per instance?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Or option 3, `Person.prototype.sayHello = function() { ... }`. The first version of your function is a bit strange because it only returns the *original* value of `name`, not the current value of `this.name`. The second version of your function won't actually work, because the variable `name` that it tries to access is not the same as the `name` argument in the function that is returned.

Comment: @nnnnnn: Actually that's the reason why the second version doesn't work at all, it will yield the value of `window.name` (which still might have a value if you called `Person` without `new`).

Comment: @Bergi - Yeah, I was just editing my comment to mention that. Although your extra point about calling `Person()` without `new` is pretty important and I didn't think to mention that.

Comment: You should only assign instance methods to `this` from inside of the constructor when that method will need access to a variable/function that is scoped to the constructor.  _All_ other instance methods should be assigned to the prototype.

Comment: A "copy of a function in memory" is probably not very expensive. Yes, it's more expensive than a solution that doesn't do that, but not by much. The code for the function is immutable, and so it can be shared by all the instances. If you're making 1,000,000 Person instances, then it matters, but if you're making 10 or 100 it probably doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you are witnessing is the result of two things:

1. Functions as first-class objects. This means functions are treated the same way as strings, numbers, arrays etc.
2. How local variables are treated in functions. Local variables are created (typically on the stack) each time the function is called. This allows functions to be called recursively.

This behavior exists in many different languages that have anonymous functions like Go, Perl, Lisp etc.

The two rules above means that each time you call your function the inner function gets created and assigned to the variable.

## What's the advantage of this?

The primary advantage of this from the language point of view is consistency of behavior. It means functions are really treated as first-class objects just like numbers, strings etc. Treating it consistently means that people who try to use anonymous functions won't get surprised by the behavior.

#### How do people use this feature?

Sometimes you find yourself writing several different functions that look similar:

```
function double (x) {return x * 2};
function quadruple (x) {return x * 4};
```

Wouldn't it be nice to be able to categorize a "family" of functions that are similar and somehow write them once?

Well, in languages like C you may use a macro system to basically cut-and-paste the text you type to generate several different code.

In languages with first-class-functions you write a function to generate functions:

```
function makeMultiplier (factor) {
    return function (x) { return x * factor }
}
```

So now you can do:

```
var double = makeMultiplier(2);
var quadruple = makeMultiplier(4);
```

Now **OBVIOUSLY** for this to work the `makeMultiplier()` function **MUST** return two different functions. It cannot just modify a single function to do different things each time it is called. Otherwise both the `double()` and `quadruple()` functions will multiply by 4 after the second call to `makeMultiplier()`.

---

## Implementation detail

It is possible to create a system whereby the body of inner functions are compiled only once and the differences are captured by a closure. So all functions only occupy RAM once but different versions of a function may occupy more than one closure. It is possible that this is how it's implemented by most js engines but I don't really know. If so, then inner functions **do** take up additional RAM each time they're defined but not by much (typically by one stack frame - so each function definition takes up the same space as a function call).

From the programmer's point of view though, inner functions must appear to work as if they're created each call because that's how you'd expect them to work.

Answer (score 0):

> For the 1st type of code, what's the benefit except wasting more memory?

The only time i'd use something like this is for quick testing of an anonymous object. An example of this would be in some sort of *factory* implementation:

```
getWidget = function(){
    return {
        foo: 'bar',
        test: function(){ ... }
    }
}
```

And honestly, this would be quickly replaced with proper coding conventions after I confirmed my initial testing.

> Should we write code in the 2nd way, or javascript should avoid one copy for one function per instance?

I'd say no. Don't write code like this. It's unnecessarily convoluted and doesn't appear to work from what I can tell.  I'd recommend just creating methods on the function prototype:

```
var Person = function(name){
    this.name = name;
}

Person.prototype.sayHello = function(){
    return 'Hello ' + this.name;
}
```

**pros**
- easy to read
- easy to manage
- `this` is scoped properly within the context of calling methods

**cons**
- a nominal increase in effort to code
- per a comment to the question, you lose access to variables scoped exclusively to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

> For the 1st type of code, what's the benefit except wasting more memory?

This could be used for access control (like `private` in some other languages).

Consider:

```
var Person=function(name){ 
   this.sayHello = function(){return 'Hello '+name;}
};
```

`name` can only be accessed by `sayHello`, which is a opaque Function.

Other code may replace `this.sayHello`, but will not be able to let this `sayHello` instance use another `name`.